# Condition only pulling records where someone from an account number calls more that 2 times for a category for last three months

Tags: sql, databricks

I want to pull all records where someone from an account number calls more that 2 times (that is volume >=2) for a category for last three months (that is month is >=4)

Tried this code below, but am getting an error in where clause, not sure what I am doing wrong, would appreciate any guidance on how to improve the code and why I might be getting this error.

```
Select distinct(topic), acct_nbr, count(acct_nbr) as volume, received_dt, month(received_dt) as month
where month > 3 and volume > 2
FROM temp.MS
group by topic, acct_nbr, received_dt, month
order by volume asc;
```

> Error in SQL statement: ParseException:  mismatched input 'FROM'
>   expecting (line 3, pos 0)
>
> == SQL == Select distinct(topic_desc), acct_nbr, count(acct_nbr) as volume, received_dt, month(received_dt) as month where month > 3 and
>   volume > 2 FROM temp.MS_CallCenter_Make_it_Right ^^^ group by
>   topic_desc, acct_nbr, received_dt, month order by volume asc

Comment: For one, the `WHERE` clause must come after the `FROM` clause.  What do your tables look like?

Comment: bjk116's answer is the reason for your error; also, using DISTINCT when you already have a GROUP BY is unnecessary.  I think you are also misusing the MONTH(received_dt) function, as that will give you the number of the month that correlates to that date, whereas your question indicates you're looking for "lasting 3 months".